# android - seekbar progress does not get painted all the way

Tags: android, seekbar

does anybody know why I am getting this (see photo)?

Here is how I set it:

```
    this._seekBar.setProgressDrawable(_context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.common_controls_player_progressbar_bg_expanded));
                this._seekBar.setThumb(_context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ringtone_scrub));
this._seekBar.setThumbOffset(0);
this._seekBar.setMax(1000);
this._seekBar.setMinimumHeight(6);
```

Seekbar itself:

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar_ctrl" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:maxHeight="6dp"/>
```

Expanded view xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
         <solid android:color="@color/player_progressbar_gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
             <solid android:color="@color/player_progressbar_gray"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                 <solid android:color="@color/player_progressbar_green"/>
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

It does happen in both expanded and collapsed view. What am I missing?

Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: it suppose to be painted green (same as scrub color) till the scrub location. But it does not do that. The seekbar is triggered by a control (ImageView) so on click all it does is shows the progress bar. So if my value was at 50% it should paint progress up till 50% but it does not do that until I actually start the control that is responsible for the progress (PLAYER). Once player starts working it paints again. But in paused mode when I look at the seekbar it is looking like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was due to the launch of two controls that I was toggling. 1. expanded mode 2. collapsed. State of the progress was lost between toggles since I was only setting one control at a time. So what I did to fix this was: I placed 2 progress bar controls on the control holder and was setting them both at the same time. One remained hidden the other one was shown. During toggle event I switched the visability. That solved the issue. The second issue we had with same control was the progress on tap would flicker back and forth before being set. It turned out to be the issue with the OS of the phone and related to the player itself. We got a new OS build release and that fixed the issue.

Comment: the point here is sometimes those things can be related to your phone and not your code.